# List all integers $x$ in $1\leq3 x \leq 100$

Tags: integers

List all integers $x$ in $1\leq x \leq 100$ that satisfy $x \equiv 3\pmod{17}$
Will it be enough if a calculate and write it as $3,20,37,54,71,88$  or I have to use any theorem?

Comment: Let's walk through this. Can you give an example of one number $x$ such that $x \equiv 3 \mod 17$?

Comment: The conditions in the title and in the question are different.

Comment: Yes it is 54 what after that

Comment: "Where should I start? What are the initial thoughts?" These are the questions which you should answer before we help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: $3$ works; $17+3=20$ works; $2\cdot 17 +3 = 34 + 3 = 37$ works. Can you carry on?

Comment: Yes I can I was thinking if I have to use a theorem

Comment: Using this method gives an exhaustive list, so I can't see a reason to.

Comment: OK thanks for the help